# JProfiler inside Docker container: The JVM you are trying to attach to is running with a different user account

Tags: docker, jprofiler

I am trying to run JProfiler inside my Docker container which is deploying my Java/Springboot application. By following the instructions provided [here](https://geekspearls.blogspot.com/2016/08/configure-jprofiler-92-to-profiling.html), I added this to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN wget http://download-keycdn.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_linux_11_0.tar.gz -P /tmp/ &&\
 tar -xzf /tmp/jprofiler_linux_11_0.tar.gz -C /usr/local &&\
 rm /tmp/jprofiler_linux_11_0.tar.gz

ENV JPAGENT_PATH="-agentpath:/usr/local/jprofiler11.0/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=nowait"
EXPOSE 8849
```

And then I enter the container to run the following inside /usr/local/jprofiler11.0:

```
bin/jpenable --gui --port=8849
```

which responds with the following error:

```
ERROR: The agent could not be loaded: 
The JVM you are trying to attach to is running with a different user account.
Please run this tool with
    sudo -u app jpenable
```

I am finding this error hard to understand because if I do a `ps` I get

```
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
   16 app       6:57 java -jar myRunningApp
```

And `whoami` confirms that I am user `app`. I also tried entering the container as `root` and the result is the same. Anyway, I am unable to run `sudo -u app jpenable` because I get bash: `sudo: command not found`, not sure if relevant. Running `uname -a`:

```
Linux 9cdef7df689d 4.9.184-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue Jul 2 22:58:16 UTC 2019 x86_64 Linux
```

Does anybody know what I am missing? Thank you for your help

Comment: In your `/tmp` directory, what directories do you have that start with `hsperfdata_` and which of them contains a file with the name of the PID that you want to attach to?

Comment: I have a directory with the PID, in this case 16

Comment: The interesting information would by the name of the directory containing the file that name, that would be the user the JVM is running as.

Comment: I'm also running into this issue @JoãoMatos did you manage to get it running?

Comment: I was not unfortunately